# Blazor text is not changed immediately upon insertion

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, mudblazor

I have an application where the user can insert text at a certain location. The text is shown on a badge on the same page. What I want is that as the user types the changes are immediately displayed in the badge.
I have added an oninput event, but it seems that the oninput event does not update the razor page because the badge remains blank when I have input changes. The text is only displayed when the focus is lost on TextField.

How can I make it so that when I insert letters, they are immediately displayed on the badge?

Textinput:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@itemAttribute.Title" @oninput="(e)=> itemAttribute.Title = e.Value.ToString()" />
```

Badge:

```
<MudBadge Overlap="false" Style="@($"color: #CFD8DC;")" Color="Color.Transparent" Content="@itemAttribute.Title">
```

Variable:

```
 [Parameter] public ItemAttribute itemAttribute { get; set; }
```

Comment: Being unfamiliar with MudBlazor, I suggest you first check if `@oninput` gets call correctly first.  Break it out into a method and put in a breakpoint.  If so calling `StateHasChanged` as part of the `@oninput` after setting `itemAttribute.Title` should trigger an update.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try simply:

```html
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@itemAttribute.Title" Immediate="true" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `StateHasChanged` method. The `StateHasChanged` method notifies the component that its state has changed. When applicable, this will cause the component to be re-rendered.

You can try this code:

Textinput:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="@itemAttribute.Title" @oninput="()=> UpdateBadge()" />
```

Badge:

```
<MudBadge @bind-Value="@BadgeContent.Title" Overlap="false" Style="@($"color: #CFD8DC;")" Color="Color.Transparent" Content="@itemAttribute.Title">
```

Code:

```
[Parameter] public ItemAttribute itemAttribute { get; set; }
[Parameter] public ItemAttribute BadgeContent { get; set; }

private void UpdateBadge()
{
   BadgeContent.Title = itemAttribute.Title;
   StateHasChanged();
}
```